# create a pandas dataframe from xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an xlsx file containing journals abstracts, author, title columns. I am trying to load a dataframe from the data for further analysis, but facing errors like encoding, memory buffer issue.
Then I tried loading only author column but the errors are same.
Can anybody suggest a solution, please?

The sample dataset

Authors

{'Oliver Jonas': 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Cambridge, MA.'}

{'Jia-Ren Lin': 'Harvard Medical School, Boston, MA;', 'Benjamin Izar': 'Dana-Farber Cancer Institute, Broad Institute of Harvard and MIT, Boston, MA;', 'Daniel Treacy': 'Dana-Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, MA;', 'Marc Wadsworth'}

Comment: Can you post the code you have been using? Specifically the code which yields encoding error?

Comment: I was using the basic read_csv function. pd.read_csv('author.xlsx',encoding = 'utf-8').Then I tried to read line by line

Comment: import csv
import pdb
with open(r"author.xlsx", 'r',encoding='latin1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    linenumber = 1
    pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        for row in reader:

Comment: I'd recommend trying pd.read_excel, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

File `authors.xlsx`:

[authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK3SU.png)

Note that I used LibreOffice Calc for editing the table, but I saved the document as .xlsx

Then I used [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for reading it:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('authors.xlsx')`

You can then query the dataframe by columns, which correctly return the values:

In: 

`df['Name']`

Out:

`0      Jia-Ren Lin
1    Benjamin Izar
2    Daniel Treacy
Name: Name, dtype: object`

Comment: Please do not include images / links in answers, unless your answer also makes sense without the image / link.